# Getting JSON data for getting places nearby like malls, restaurants and famous locations

Tags: android, json

Is there any source from which i can get the nearby json data. I will pass the latitude and longitude and it should give me the data within specified radius. I am developing android application and i need to retrieve that data to augment on camera.

Comment: if only there was a website I could use to search for APIs. https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Comment: refer this one http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Google Places API :) It can give both xml and json data. Which ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google places API. It will done all of this work. Voteup or mark True If helpful

Answer (score 1):

Google APIs may meet your needs, but they are not the only game in town.  Two other good data sources are FourSquare and Yelp.

Google Places API
    https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Foursquare
    https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues

Yelp
    http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business

I've used all three in the past with good success.  Yelp has more detailed data, but their attribution clauses make it less appealing to use.  Foursquare data is pretty good and easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project in google api provide the details like name and you package name and your sha1 key then click android in that. After that it show new key there you find generate new keys(browser,server,android) you can create the keys for both browser and android.

[Refer this for creating api keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

enable the following services in google Api console

1.Google Maps API v2

2.Places API

3.Analytics API

Refer this one [Show near by places source](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/)

add the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="(YourPackageName).permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```